# Function usage in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can find one scalar valued function in one database.

I just want to know where that function is being used like in any stored procedure or any view.

Is there any query to check this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could download [SQL Search by RedGate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) if you're allowed to install things.

Alternatively you could script out the database, Right Click on your database -> Tasks -> Generate Scripts. This will script out the entire database (any objects you select) and will take a while on a larger system. Once it's finished you'll be able to use Ctrl+F to search and see where the function is called.